# yii2 select2 widget allow new tags with autocomplete

Tags: jquery-select2, yii2

I use Krajee select2 widget.
For now i have this code:

```
<?php
echo '<label class="control-label">Tag Content</label>';
echo Select2::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'tags',
    'name' => 'tags',
    'data' => Tag::getTags(),
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Select a color ...',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'multiple' => true,
    ],]);
?>
```

This is working, but i need also allow users to eneter new tags (not ionly using tags from model). What i need to do to achieve this?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable tags mode you need to specify `tags` option in `pluginOptions`.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'tags')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Select a color ...',
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'tags' => Tag::getTags(),
    ],
]) ?>
```

I also removed redundant options (assuming you are using it inside `ActiveForm`).

You can read more in official extension [documentation](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2). There is also an example of preselecting values.

Comment: Any idea how to make it work with ajax hints? It doesn't work when you try to update model - tags are not loaded correctly

Comment: @Joe Coud you provide more info?

Comment: Sure,  I added issue to github: https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widgets/issues/281